# PWM to synth control voltage improvements

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, analog, pwm, atmega

Just built this little circuit to control my Moog Werkstatt. The plan is to make a MIDI-to-CV converter and add more CV outputs and of course a GATE output later. But before going further, I thought I'd ask if this circuit could be improved.

CV in this context stands for "Control Voltage" and is used to control the frequency of the oscillator in the synth. The Moog Werkstatt changes the pitch by 1 octave per volt.

[image: My CV circuit]

The Atmel chip sends a 0–5V PWM signal at 133.333kHz. After filtering the PWM output it is scaled to -5-+5V (which is what the Werkstatt expects). I want to be able to tune the signal so therefore I let a voltage divider turn the signal down to roughly 4.5V and then I have an amplifier which can turn it up to 5.5V (and be adjusted by a potentiometer).

It works well and I'm quite satisfied with the performance but maybe there are some obvious faults with the design that might affect stability? Perhaps there should be a buffer somewhere in the circuit? Will R2 and R3 change value over time and cause unbalance?

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: What is "CV" in this context?

Comment: Control voltage. Do you think I should edit the title?

Comment: I think you should explain exactly what control voltage is in this context, as I for one have no experience with synthesizers at all.

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry! Thanks for the suggestion! I'll edit my post to make it clearer.

Comment: Or maybe I should have just answered here in the comment field instead of editing my post? :O

Comment: Editing the post is always preferred.

Comment: VR1 will drift with time unless you have a very good one but the resistors are very stable. The very situation you are describing is the key feature of the opamp, the gain and filter constants are set by passive external components. This was a major challenge before the opamp was invented by some Scott IIRC.

Comment: The integrated PWM voltage on C3 is going to be proportional to the voltage at the output pin. The load (R1) is low enough that it's not going to affect it, but the regulation of the supply to the ATMEGA, and to the reference point at R2 would, so you need to look at the the performance of that regulator. For stability, you could use a separate reference for the PWM and op-amp reference, a 5.6V Zener and a spare op-amp as a buffer would eliminate issues with load variation and thermal coefficient.

Comment: @winny Thanks, nice to know I can rely on the resistors.

Comment: @Phil G Interesting. So, would it be better to run +9V through a 5.6V Zener, into an op-amp buffer which in turn supplies the reference voltage at R2? But wouldn't that risk making the output from IC1a unbalanced? I've probably misunderstood. :)

Comment: The scaling of the output depends on both the reference at R2, and the amplitude at D3. If the power regulator is stable and does not vary under load, all will be well, but you're relying on that for consistency. Ideally both would come from stable references, likely the same one. To use a reference at the PWM input (R1) you'd need to use D3 to switch a FET connected to that reference,so that variation in supply voltage doesn't affect the PWM integration.

Comment: This is invaluable information, thank you! So following your suggestion will make sure the output from IC1a will be consistent under most circumstances? Will a MOSFET to the job? If I've understood correctly, I can take my +9V and run them through a 5.6V zener and into a buffer. The output from the buffer is then connected to R2 and to a FET. Or is the FET to be connected between the zener and the buffer? (Sorry for the stupid questions.)